# ng-show takes two clicks to start toggling

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to hide / show a div based upon a click. When the page loads the div is hidden which is the intended behavior but I have to click twice to get it to start toggling. What am I missing over here?

This is my code

```
<a href ng-click="ShowOrHide('01')" class="list-group-item">Night 1</a> <div ng-show="showNight">{{night}}</div>
```

and this is the angular module

```
var MyApp = angular.module("MyModule", []);
MyApp .controller("MyController", function ($scope){
    $scope.test = "This is from angular";
    $scope.showNight = "false";
    $scope.ShowOrHide = function(night){
        $scope.night = "night " + night;
        $scope.showNight = !$scope.showNight;
    };

});
```

Comment: false and "false" are not same

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are setting `$scope.showNight` to the string `"false"`, which is truthy, as a non-empty string. If you set `$scope.showNight` to `false` (not as a string), it should be fixed.

[More info on truthy and falsy values in JS](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

Answer (score 0):

After clicking two times   `$scope.showNight` goes set to `boolean` true.

```
$scope.showNight = false;
            $scope.ShowOrHide = function(night) {
                $scope.night = "night " + night;
                $scope.showNight = !$scope.showNight;
            };
```

Comment: Thank you guys. That was not very smart of me doing "false" within quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$scope.showNight = false;` instead of `$scope.showNight = "false";`.